# app.js sometimes returns TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on full questions

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I'm using the Microsoft code samples to try and create a LUIS bot that uses an intent to trigger the QNA Maker.

At the moment the QnA Maker returns results sometimes but other times it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

The question "Price change" with the following code returns the correct answer from QnA maker.

```
var customQnAMakerTools = new customQnAMakerTools.CustomQnAMakerTools();
bot.library(customQnAMakerTools.createLibrary());


var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer, 
r12recognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

var basicQnAMakerDialog = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [r12recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'Sorry i did not understand that. Try asking the 
question again.',
    qnaThreshold: 0.3,
    feedbackLib: customQnAMakerTools
});

intents.matches('qna', [
basicQnAMakerDialog.respondFromQnAMakerResult = function(session, 
qnaMakerResult){
// Save the question
var question = session.message.text;
session.conversationData.userQuestion = question;
// boolean to check if the result is formatted for a card


var isCardFormat = qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer.includes(';');
if(!isCardFormat){
    // Not semi colon delimited, send a normal text response 
    session.send(qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer);
}else if(qnaMakerResult.answers && qnaMakerResult.score >= 0.5){

    var qnaAnswer = qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer;
            var qnaAnswerData = qnaAnswer.split(';');
            var title = qnaAnswerData[0];
            var description = qnaAnswerData[1];
            var url = qnaAnswerData[2];
            var imageURL = qnaAnswerData[3];

            var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            msg.attachments([
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title(title)
                .subtitle(description)
                .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, imageURL)])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, url, "Learn More")
                ])
            ]);
    }
session.send(msg).endDialog();
}


]);
```

However, if I change the question to "Price change approved but finally rejected by the System" which is the full question in QnA Maker it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". The full error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Array.intents.matches.basicQnAMakerDialog.respondFromQnAMakerResult (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:71:46)
    at Object.waterfallHandler [as qna] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\WaterfallDialog.js:139:29)
    at IntentDialog.invokeIntent (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentDialog.js:163:44)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentDialog.js:71:27
    at next (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:68:17)
    at IntentRecognizerSet.IntentRecognizer.filter (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:71:9)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizer.js:20:31
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\IntentRecognizerSet.js:80:17
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at replenish (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:306:28)
```

I cant currently workout if its because I'm passing the question incorrectly or if its only passing part of the question.

Comment: Looks like a case where QnaMaker did not had a reply, so `qnaMakerResult.answers[0]` throws the exception as `answers` is not defined? Did you have a look directly to your QnA, to test the value you are passing?

Comment: When i've asked the question to the QnA maker in both the testing area and as a bot service it passes back the correct answer its only inside the LUIS intent where it throws this

"Price change approved but finally rejected by the System" is the actual full question in the qna knowledge base with the QnA Pair.

Comment: Does your 2 cases have the same reply?

Comment: Yep both should return the same response

Comment: Ok.. sorry but can't help more without the QnA data

Comment: which line is throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"?

Comment: It seems to indicate the following section is at fault  session.send(qnaMakerResult.answers[0].answer); }else if(qnaMakerResult.answers && qnaMakerResult.score >= 0.5){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen when you have an intent in LUIS with the same name. Once the intent is deleted the QnA intent will kick off correctly and send the messages to the QnA Knowledge base.

Comment: Just attempted this and it appears to work, not sure why. Thank you!

This also made it possible to start pulling in answers from multiple knowledge bases whilst also still using LUIS